# CPU 99% after installing workflow manager

Tags: workflow-manager

I have a VM with 12 GB RAM, 120 G disk space, on SSD, it was working fast and so on, then I installed workflow manager, and then windows made some updates which took a while to get updated. Now I am having the CPU at 99%, and I don't know if the problem from the workflow manager or from the updates. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you check the task manager which process is consuming the more CPU? or user Perfmon....Alos try to restart the VM.

Comment: Restarting didn't work. The process is IIS Worker process.